# Delete word group in Vim

Tags: vim

I am in vim editing a python file, how can you delete the sequence `throw=it,`? After searching online I see the command daw, but that doesn't work with this word group.

```
one two three throw=it, now
```

Comment: dE, diW, daW - note the capital W

Comment: :help motion.txt will blow your mind.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

another way is `daW`. with a capital W, it will delete any sequence of non-space characters, regardless of where inside the sequence you are.

This is different from `dE`, because `dE` only deletes from the cursor until the next end of the sequence of non-space characters, whereas `daW` will also delete the whole sequence between whitespaces.

Comment: `diW` will delete just the sequence, while `daW` will also delete some surrounding spaces. I don't exactly remember how `aW` works though.

Answer (score 2):

assuming cursor is at the start of `throw=it`, `dE` should do the trick

```
E           Forward to the end of WORD [count] |inclusive|.
            Does not stop in an empty line.
```

Comment: actually this isn't what i'm looking for, i just realized.  cause as you say it presumes the cursor is at the start of the word group.

Answer (score 0):

Another way is `Bdt<space>`. Note your cursor can be on any character on `throw=it,`

`B`: puts the cursor at the very front of the block after the preceding space

`dt<space>`: delete till space

Answer (score 0):

Use <kbd>c</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to delete your sequence and enter insert mode.

Use <kbd>d</kbd><kbd>a</kbd><kbd>W</kbd> to delete your sequence and stay in normal mode.